# Group ranges in table with non-time-based start and end columns

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I need to find the ranges in consecutive data points that may have gaps between them based on double precision start and end columns.

For simplicity let's call them **startPoint** and **endPoint** which track a position on a line. The difference between the endPoint and the startPoint would denominate a distance. Over this "distance" particular force/effect signal values are captured and based on the values a **state** is stored on the table. Each row has a unique **id** identifier.

Thus, the table looks like the following:

```
| id | startPoint | endPoint | state    |
|----|------------|----------|----------|
| 1  | 0.0        | 5.8      | Active   |
| 2  | 5.8        | 7.1      | Inactive |
| 3  | 7.5        | 10.2     | Inactive |
| 4  | 10.2       | 11.3     | Inactive |
| 5  | 11.6       | 12.1     | Active   |
| 6  | 12.1       | 12.9     | Active   |
```

I have struggled to come up with a query that works in **PostgresSQL** that yields the following result:

```
| startGap   | endGap   | state    |
|------------|----------|----------|
| 0.0        | 5.8      | Active   |
| 5.8        | 7.1      | Inactive |
| 7.5        | 11.3     | Inactive |
| 11.6       | 12.9     | Active   |
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't get why consecutive  `Inactive` group have 2 row in expected result

Comment: It seems there is no information between 7.1 and  7.5

Comment: Between 5.8 and 7.1 a known "Inactive" state is seen. We have no information of what happened between  7.1 and 7.5 so it cannot be grouped with the defined "Inactive" state.

Comment: @Horaciux - thanks, got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You can identify where a group starts using `lag()` and then use cumulative sums:

```
select min(startPoint) as startPoint, max(endPoint) as endPoint, state
from (select t.*,
             sum( (prev_endPoint is distinct from startPoint)::int) over () as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(endPoint) over (partition by state order by startPoint) as prev_endPoint
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by state, grp;
```

To be honest, floating point numbers are rather dangerous, because two could look the same.  The `sum()` defining `grp` is probably better written as:

```
sum( (abs(prev_endPoint - startPoint) > 0.001)::int) over () as grp
```

I would also suggest that you switch to fixed point representation (numeric) rather than floating point.

Comment: I think [`sum` need to be made into window function](http://rextester.com/ZXI66822) i.e. with `over (partition by`. Great solution though +1